# How to map to timestamp when return data from database using nestjs and graphql

Tags: postgresql, graphql, nestjs, hasura

I use nestjs and graphql save data into postgres.
When i save data it save success on my database. Here dto input

```
@InputType()
export class CreateShop {
  //some field


  @Field(() => String, { name: 'opening_time' })
  openingTime?: Timestamp;

  @Field(() => String, { name: 'closing_time' })
  closingTime?: Timestamp;
```

}

My data save success on database but when i get data with **openingTime** field and **closingTime** field it cannot parse to timestamp.

Here  my response dto

```
@ObjectType()
export class CreateShopResponse {
  @Field(() => GraphQLISODateTime)
  opening_time: Date;
  @Field( () => GraphQLISODateTime)
  closing_time: Date;
}
```

When i get data it throw me error :

```
"Error: Expected `DateTime.serialize(\"2023-10-10 10:10:10\")` to return non-nullable value, returned: null",
```

When i change **opening_time** and **closing_time** to String on **CreateShopResponse** it return success.
I have a question : How to convert. **timestamp** from database to nestjs + graphql using type timestamp.
Note : **openingTime** and  **closingTime** on database when save success have type look like :
**`2023-10-10 17:30:30.000 +0700`**